# Ordering values entered in Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, metabox

I found a great article on Custom Taxonomies [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/taking-wordpress-custom-taxonomies-to-the-next-level/#comment-47312). I have a specific requirement related to ordering values entered in the Custom Taxonomies. How do I display the terms entered in the meta boxes in the order I entered them and “NOT” in alphabetical order.(ex. If I enter Edward, Linda, Arnold in meta boxes, how do I NOT display them Arnold, Edward, Linda).

Thanks in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To print its categories that article uses the function wp_list_categories. The parameter that dictates how elements are ordered is "order_by" which it sets to "name". Other options are listed under parameters, order by, on that function's page in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

It seems that the option you have are ID, name, slug, term_group and count. Anything else will require more work than just changing a parameter. The solution might depend on what kind of sorting you are looking for.

Comment: Calle, thanks for your response. I tried changing the name to "id" for the orderby and it does exactly what I want. But the problem is that it displays "all" the taxonomies terms. I want to display only the ones specific to my custom post. I am currently using "get_the_term_list" method but it displays taxonomy terms in alphabetical order.

Comment: get_the_term_list is a helper function that retrieves terms and prints them in a list. The best you can do if you want to change the order is to use wp_get_object_terms (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) and print the list yourself as in the example on the page I just gave a link to. It takes a list of arguments, of which one is orderby, just like wp_list_categories.

Comment: Nice! That method was exactly what I needed and has worked out for me. Thanks.